# How to consume a HTTP response page (with XML as response) periodically in Android?

Tags: android, http, push, google-cloud-messaging

I have a simple page that updates itself and generates a response in XML.

http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/Pregao-Online/ExecutaAcaoAjax.asp?CodigoPapel=PETRK14|petrw14

I wonder how do I consume this page every 1 min showing these variations to the user in Android, i need the GCM or some other tool to push or is not necessary in this case? I've read all about the GCM and as I already have a WebService HTTP i would not need to configure another server.

I appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: You just need a Timer scheduled minutely to let a webview load the page for instance.

Comment: @greenapps the APP needs to be running all the time, like a service, then when some variation appear it will trigger a function and send some notifications to the user. Do you know how I do that?

Comment: If a change occurs it could send a notification indeed. You could still use a timer to trigger a new download. Then compare with the old one.